# Doppler Effect and Speed relativity

Tags: waves, acoustics, doppler-effect

I calculated that the frequency of the sound that reaches a recipient
achieved when the recipient remains stationary and the source is towards him (vS = 34m / s) is not equal to the frequency of the sound that reaches the recipient when he is moving with a speed of vR = 34m / s towards a
dormant source. I look again at the formular and see that the speed of sound that reaches the recipient when he moves towards a stationary sound source depends on his speed. So the relative speed of the sound reaching the recipient is the sum of the speed of sound (343m / s) and his own Speed (vR). The speed of sound that reaches the recepient when he stands still and the sound source moves towards him is independent  of the speed of the source (vQ). I would like to know why it is so.

Comment: Did your calculation not show you why it is so?

Answer (score 1):

> The speed of sound that reaches the recepient when he stands still and
>   the sound source moves towards him is independent of the speed of the
>   source (vQ). I would like to know why it is so.

The speed of sound propagation is determined by the properties of the medium - air, in this case - and does not depend on the speed of a source.

Let's consider an example.

It is known that you cannot hear a plane approaching you at a supersonic speed. This, of course, is because the plane moves faster than the sound it produces. When the plane moves away from you, though, you can hear it.

If the speed of sound depended on the speed of a source, the effect would be opposite.